# positioning a div within a div in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

First question here, and also not really trained well so if I ask it wrong, just let me know!

I'm working on a page in a jungle of a Wordpress site at my job, where who knows who was managing it before. I mention Wordpress since I feel like I've run into odd problems before, like just not being able to make ordered lists and not finding anything in the CSS that should prevent it...

I've been tasked with working on a new home page design, where I'm trying to make sort of a grid of 2 rows by 3 columns, to better display all of the things we offer, more equally. So that is the desired end result, in case anyone has a simple alternative entirely. :)

I've been using divs and letting them fall, and I've been having luck with just:

```
#homecolumn {
    width:29%;
    float:left;
    padding:10px; 
    text-align: center;
    height:450px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;  
}
```

up in the style section, and listing six  sections with different content within each. It lays out as desired.

(Aside question: I was under the impression that this was a situation for div classes because I want to use it multiple times. But when I try to use classes, it just shows up as a list blob.)

Within each of these homecolumn sections, I have a button thing, currently coded as:

```
<div>
<a style="background-color: #0088cc; border-radius: 10px; color: #fff; font-  family: helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 500; padding: 10px 30px; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" href="">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

(with a URL in there of course)

And that works okay. I wanted the button to appear at the bottom of each homecolumn section instead of just below whatever text there is so that they line up visually, so I tried to add 
position: relative;    bottom: 0px;

in the style but it doesn't affect anything. Changing position to absolute sure does, but the "bottom:" can change and not do anything.

Furthermore I also tried to make a div id up in the style tags for "homebutton" using the same style elements as in the code above so I could just do  and add a link to appear within, but that does not work.

```
#homebutton {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #0088cc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    adding: 10px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I've tried some combination of trying classes vs ids again and no luck. What am I doing wrong in trying to put this div within a div and positioning it?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you put the relevant HTML and CSS in a codepen or jsbin and include that in the question?

Comment: Can you show how `#homebutton` is related to `<a>` links?

Comment: Use classes. If your classes are not working is because of something is wrong within your css specificity. Also remove that space between `font-` and `family`

Comment: Putting the code in codepen probably wouldn't help in this case since everything really does seem to just behave differently on this wordpress page. I don't know if it makes sense but I am not comfortable sharing the actual page since it is for work. I wish I had access to the back-end so I could just edit the page file directly. Classes really aren't working right so I think I'll delve into the main stylesheet. Thank you all for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the 3 column effect. Be mindful that this is not a responsive
 design solution, If you want something responsive, you'll have to employ media queries or a responsive framework that will make your life a whole lot easier.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="homecolumn">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Anything here</p>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
        </div>
        <div class="homecolumn">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Anything here</p>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
        </div>
        <div class="homecolumn">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Anything here</p>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="homecolumn">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Anything here</p>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
        </div>
        <div class="homecolumn">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Anything here</p>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
        </div>
        <div class="homecolumn">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Anything here</p>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    width:900px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#ddd;
}
.row{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
.homecolumn{
    width:26%;
    margin:0 15px;
    padding: 18px;
    background:#999;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}

 .button{
    background-color: #0088cc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/ZQmNrO)

**Something to learn:**

Any front end engineer worth his/her salt will agree with me when I say, use Classes instead of IDs to style your HTML document in your CSS. For various reasons, but most importantly because:

- IDs are unique to a single document, if you want to reuse that style, you will need a Class in order to share properly and effectively.
- Classes allow you to cascade, IDs do not.
- Cleanliness is next to godliness - when you are an organized developer, you can always count to find IDs in your Javascript and Classes in your Stylesheets

Comment: Thanks so much for your great example! Unfortunately I think the problem is a little deeper so I'll have to change strategies. Using your sample code this happens: http://imgur.com/LdpyFbh but mysteriously if I change them from classes to ids it's a little better...http://imgur.com/LAVIYoV. Either way the button formatting doesn't show up.

Comment: Are you using a responsive framework (Bootstrap, Foundation, etc?) When you inspect the source with F-12, do you see these boxes rendering something along these lines `@media (width:768px){ .homecolumn {width:100%;} }`. It looks like it is overwriting the 26% width I coded which it's something RWD frameworks would do to ensure they stack this way at a certain width.

Comment: I will take a closer look, but any idea why it somehow works better with reused IDs? That just doesn't seem to behave correctly either.

Comment: Hard to know without inspecting the code, but I am 99.9999% positive the IDs have some styling assigned to them somewhere that is affecting this. It's the only way the IDs could alter the foirnt end styling. Other than javascript hardcoded properties.